# Find test current in Thevenin circuit

Tags: thevenin, linear, circuit-analysis

I deactivated all the independent sources and removed the load resistance across terminals a and b, then applied test voltage Vt=1V across 1V. I have to find It. 
My calculations: It=i2-i1

Mesh 1: -1 + 11k i1 =0 => i1 =0.09 mA

Mesh 2: -1 + 5.6k(i2-i3)=0

i2-i3= 0.178 mA

Mesh 3: 2k i3 + 5.6k(i3-i2)=0

7.6k i3 -5.6k i2 =0

7.6k(i2-0.178mA) -5.6 k i2=0

2k i2 = 1.35

i2=0.6 mA

It=0.51mA

R thevinin = 1/0.51mA= 1960.7 Ohms whereas the answer should be around 570-600(as 
etermined experimentally)

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Both answers seem wrong to me. I didn't check your calculations, but you are complicating matters a lot. If you don't consider your test generator, your circuit is a simple parallel/series combination of resistors: \$R_1\$ is in series with \$R_5\$ (call the result \$R_{15}=R_1+R_5=11k\Omega\$). This latter is in parallel with both \$R_2\$ and \$R_4\$, so your Thèvenin equivalent resistance is:

$$
R_{th}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R_{15}} + \dfrac{1}{R_2} + \dfrac{1}{R_4}}\approx1.3k\Omega
$$